# Different Leaflet fillcolors for different layers

Tags: leaflet, geojson, layers, choropleth

I have a leaflet map set up with two layers and I want them to use different colorization functions to color the choropleth shapes.

My shapes are set up in layers like this:

```
var povertyLayer = L.geoJson(statesData,  {
          style: getStyle,
          onEachFeature: onEachFeature
      });

      var raceLayer = L.geoJson(statesData,  {
          style: getStyle2,
          onEachFeature: onEachFeature
      });

      var rLayer = L.layerGroup([raceLayer]);
      var povLayer = L.layerGroup([povertyLayer]);
```

They're styled by different functions:

```
 function getStyle(feature) {
          return {
              weight: 2,
              opacity: 0.2,
              color: '#333',
              fillOpacity: 0.7,
              fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.inpoverty)
          };
      }
      function getStyle2(feature) {
          return {
              weight: 2,
              opacity: 0.2,
              color: '#333',
              fillOpacity: 0.7,
              fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.ratio)
          };
      }
```

But they use the same accessor function to apply colorization to geojson features:

```
function getColor(d) {
        if (regionalDataset == 'inpoverty') {
           return d > 25 ? '#f4bd33' :
            d > 15 ? '#fac961' :
            d > 10 ? '#ffd78a' :
            d > 5 ? '#ffe5b3' :
            d > 0   ? '#fff2d9' :
            '#fff';
          } else {
        return d > 200 ? '#5E5989' :
            d > 150 ? 'rgb(110, 106, 150)' :
            d > 100 ? 'rgb(152, 149, 184)' :
            d > 50 ? 'rgb(189, 187, 215)' :
            d > 0   ? 'rgb(233, 232, 251)' :
            '#fff';
        }
      }
```

The layers are added and removed from an external button:

```
$('#regional-map-poverty')
        .on('click', function() { console.log('test1');
          d3.select(this).classed('select-regional-style-active',true);
          d3.select('#regional-map-race').classed('select-regional-style-active',false);

          regionalDataset = 'inpoverty';
          regionalDatasetTipText = '% live below the poverty line.'

           map.removeLayer(rLayer);
            map.addLayer(povLayer);
        });
```

When mousing over the shapes, the colorization on mouseover is different than the actual shapes are colored.

Mouseover code:

```
function mousemove(e) {
          var layer = e.target;

          popup.setLatLng(e.latlng);
          popup.setContent('<div class="marker-title">' + layer.feature.properties['GEO.displa'] + '</div>' +
              d3.round(layer.feature.properties[regionalDataset],1) + regionalDatasetTipText);

          if (!popup._map) popup.openOn(map);
          window.clearTimeout(closeTooltip);

          // highlight feature
          layer.setStyle({
              opacity: 0.7,
              fillOpacity:1
          });

          if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera) {
              layer.bringToFront();
          }
      }

      function mouseout(e) {

          var layer = e.target;

         layer.setStyle({
              opacity: 0.3,
              fillOpacity:.9
          });
         // raceLayer.resetStyle(e.target);

          closeTooltip = window.setTimeout(function() {
              map.closePopup();
          }, 300);
      }
```

Comment: it's not entirely clear what your question is. Is it about color on mouseover?

Comment: Yes. How to have multiple mouseover color schemes for multiple layers.

Comment: can you post the mouseover code?

Comment: Adding. I ended up solving it.

Comment: Hey @Incodeveritas can you please add your code as an answer to the question, just in case someone else has the same question in the future.